# HTML CSS JS formatting of display: none

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Initially, my `id="Gabel"` display was shown on my page with the correct format but when input display: none; my formatting was distorted. Is there anything wrong with my code? I want to show display id="Gabel" when I click the image on the main page.  Here are some of the codes. My problem lies in the formatting of my card with an id of Gabel. Thank you

```css
#Gabel {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.356);
  padding: 0;
  top: 300px;
  /* display: none; */
  width: 80%;
}

.container_Gabel img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.container_Gabel .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fc9400;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 22px 45px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294);
}


.container__text {
  padding: 40px 40px 0;
}

.container__text h1 {
  color: #351897;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container__text p {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.container__text .container__text__timing {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}

.container__text .container__text__timing .container__text__timing_time {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.container__text .container__text__timing h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.second_half {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container__text .container__text__timing p {
  color: #351897;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.title-container {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.title-container span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 10em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 2em;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function clearBox(elementID) {
            document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
            var x = document.getElementById("Gabel");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><button class="button button1">Main Menu</button></div>
    <div id="image">
        <div class="row" id="container-item">
            <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>GABEL LOFFEL</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
                        <button class="button2" onclick="clearBox('container-item')">
                        <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" alt="">
                        </button>
                        <div class="content">
                            <hr>
                            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                <p>Get out your <br> Lederhosen!</p>
                            </div>

                            <hr>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container_Gabel" id="Gabel">
        <div class="title-container"><span>
                <h2>GABEL LOFFEL</h2>
            </span></div>
        <div>
            <img src="assets\swiss.jpg" alt="Pancake" />
        </div>
        <div class="container__text">
            <h1>Gabel Loffell</h1>
            <div class="container__text__timing">
                <div class="container__text__timing_time">
                    <h2>
                        235 GLENDALE AVE.<br>
                        MERIDIAN CITY<br>
                        T: 490 49 4000<br>
                        W: GANDG.RES
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="container__text__timing_time vl"></div>
                <div class="container__text__timing_time">
                    <h2 class="second_half">
                        CATEGORY: SWISS<br>
                        OPEN: 10AM TO 10PM<br>
                        PRICE: $$$
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="body_container">
                <div class="body_card">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porttitor sodales purus, id
                        accumsan est sodales sed. Aenean tempus laoreet molestie. Ut leo ipsum, euismod a ante vitae,
                        dapibus porttitor orci. Suspendisse nec porta urna. Proin neque neque, imperdiet laoreet turpis
                        a, tincidunt convallis neque. Nunc sed nisi tristique, auctor sapien sit amet, rutrum massa. Nam
                        non enim placerat, egestas risus id, tincidunt nisl. Quisque vestibulum dolor non pharetra
                        fermentum. Sed vestibulum sapien dui, ut mollis augue luctus ac. Sed magna ex, interdum sit amet
                        velit ac, elementum scelerisque tortor. Cras eget maximus diam.

                        <br><br>Aliquam ultrices varius lorem sed elementum. Aenean rutrum efficitur suscipit. In quis
                        ligula nulla. Aliquam dictum ex ut metus vulputate feugiat. Phasellus sagittis consequat dolor,
                        id molestie ante tempus at. Sed ullamcorper velit id nulla mollis cursus. Vivamus nisl dolor,
                        posuere vehicula congue vel, ullamcorper ac nulla. Suspendisse iaculis enim tellus, ut congue
                        turpis dapibus ac. In congue nulla id gravida pellentesque. Donec rutrum urna nec metus
                        tristique, a commodo dui porta. Etiam semper, lacus non eleifend imperdiet, ipsum diam vulputate
                        eros, non laoreet ligula nibh vel lorem. Ut eu volutpat turpis. Nulla lobortis, velit ut varius
                        sollicitudin, nibh elit ornare diam, vel viverra odio orci a dui. Donec vel nulla vitae ex
                        imperdiet congue ut id metus. Sed sit amet condimentum eros.
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `display:none` means don't display - so, what formatting do you expect on something not displayed?

Comment: @JaromandaX, when my display is no none, it shows up with the correct formatting but when I don't want to show the card initially and call it in the javascript (when i clicked a button) my card is distorted or not the same. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try toggling `opacity` instead of `display`

```css
#Gabel {
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        border-radius: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.356);
        padding: 0;
        top: 300px;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .container_Gabel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    }

    .container_Gabel .btn {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -20px;
        right: -20px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #fc9400;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 22px 45px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294);
    }


    .container__text {
        padding: 40px 40px 0;
    }

    .container__text h1 {
        color: #351897;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .container__text p {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .container__text .container__text__timing {
        display: flex;
        margin: 20px 0 10px;
    }

    .container__text .container__text__timing .container__text__timing_time {
        margin-right: 40px;
    }

    .container__text .container__text__timing h2 {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .second_half {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .container__text .container__text__timing p {
        color: #351897;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .title-container {
        background: yellow;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        writing-mode: tb-rl;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    }

    .title-container span {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 10em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 2em;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 2em;
    }

    .vl {
        border-left: 4px solid black;
        height: 100px;
    }

    hr {
        border: 0;
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <script>
    function clearBox(elementID) {
        document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
        var x = document.getElementById("Gabel");
        if (x.style.opacity === "0") {
            x.style.opacity = "0";
        } else {
            x.style.opacity = "1";
        }
    }

    
</script>

<body>
<div><button class="button button1">Main Menu</button></div>
<div id="image">
    <div class="row" id="container-item">
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>GABEL LOFFEL</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
                    <button class="button2" onclick="clearBox('container-item')"><img src="assets\image_1.jpg"
                            alt=""></button>
                    <div class="content">
                        <hr>
                        <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p>Get out your <br> Lederhosen!</p>
                        </div>

                        <hr>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<div class="container_Gabel" id="Gabel">
    <div class="title-container"><span>
            <h2>GABEL LOFFEL</h2>
        </span></div>
    <div>
        <img src="assets\swiss.jpg" alt="Pancake" />
    </div>
    <div class="container__text">
        <h1>Gabel Loffell</h1>
        <div class="container__text__timing">
            <div class="container__text__timing_time">
                <h2>
                    235 GLENDALE AVE.<br>
                    MERIDIAN CITY<br>
                    T: 490 49 4000<br>
                    W: GANDG.RES
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="container__text__timing_time vl"></div>
            <div class="container__text__timing_time">
                <h2 class="second_half">
                    CATEGORY: SWISS<br>
                    OPEN: 10AM TO 10PM<br>
                    PRICE: $$$
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="body_container">
            <div class="body_card">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porttitor sodales purus, id
                    accumsan est sodales sed. Aenean tempus laoreet molestie. Ut leo ipsum, euismod a ante vitae,
                    dapibus porttitor orci. Suspendisse nec porta urna. Proin neque neque, imperdiet laoreet turpis
                    a, tincidunt convallis neque. Nunc sed nisi tristique, auctor sapien sit amet, rutrum massa. Nam
                    non enim placerat, egestas risus id, tincidunt nisl. Quisque vestibulum dolor non pharetra
                    fermentum. Sed vestibulum sapien dui, ut mollis augue luctus ac. Sed magna ex, interdum sit amet
                    velit ac, elementum scelerisque tortor. Cras eget maximus diam.

                    <br><br>Aliquam ultrices varius lorem sed elementum. Aenean rutrum efficitur suscipit. In quis
                    ligula nulla. Aliquam dictum ex ut metus vulputate feugiat. Phasellus sagittis consequat dolor,
                    id molestie ante tempus at. Sed ullamcorper velit id nulla mollis cursus. Vivamus nisl dolor,
                    posuere vehicula congue vel, ullamcorper ac nulla. Suspendisse iaculis enim tellus, ut congue
                    turpis dapibus ac. In congue nulla id gravida pellentesque. Donec rutrum urna nec metus
                    tristique, a commodo dui porta. Etiam semper, lacus non eleifend imperdiet, ipsum diam vulputate
                    eros, non laoreet ligula nibh vel lorem. Ut eu volutpat turpis. Nulla lobortis, velit ut varius
                    sollicitudin, nibh elit ornare diam, vel viverra odio orci a dui. Donec vel nulla vitae ex
                    imperdiet congue ut id metus. Sed sit amet condimentum eros.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem lies when I want to go back to the main page when clicking Main Menu Button. Would you be able to help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try using visibility property, which leaves an element in normal document flow, display: none essentially removes the element completely from the document.

[Here](https://www.thoughtco.com/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-3466884), if you need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
visibility:hidden;
```

and

```
visibility: visible;
```

to hide and show the element